# Xcode won't detect an iPhone 5 device with iOS 6.1.4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm having a problem running my app on an iPhone 5 device with iOS 6.1.4. Xcode won't recognize the device. It will recognize and run the app on an iPad with 6.1.3.

also, I'm using Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a) and iTunes 11.0.2

[image: Xcode architecture screenshot]

[image: Organizer screenshot]

thanks for any help.

Comment: It's important to stay current. You need the latest version of Xcode to use the latest versions of iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this message is stating is that the device has a higher OS version than Xcode has. You can fix this by downloading the OS file from the developer portal and copying it to Xcode. This is mainly so Xcode can restore your device or load a newer version (if needed).

Which version of Xcode are you using? It may be possible that you need to update Xcode and iTunes to get your phone working to install applications. It can be touchy that way sometimes.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm using Xcode Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a) and iTunes 11.0.2. Which OS file from the developer portal should I copy to Xcode? thanks

Comment: That is likely your issue. Xcode is now version 4.6.2 and iTunes is 11.0.3. Update Xcode to the latest version and your issues should be fixed.

Comment: It is possible that the developer portal won't have that file. They usually include them during the beta period, but bug fix builds don't usually show up. Xcode will have what it needs to run on your device at that point, so the file isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I am just having this issue after installing iOS 6.1.4. 
My solution is to enable my iPhone 5 for development by following steps:

1. Xcode > Window > Organizer
2. select your iPhone 5 in left panel. And now there is no green dot
3. enable "iphone for development" in right panel
4. there should be a green dot if everything is OK