# Running ios7 application on ios6 device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have developed application using iOS 6 . Now as there is requirement I have updated my application with iOS 7 look and feel with some UI changes . And it is running well on iOS 7  device . But how can I use same application to run on iOS 6 device with iOS look and feel. I have set the deployment target to 5 . The first problem is my Xcode 5 is not detecting the iOS 6 device . can anybody help me ?

Comment: Will [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750233/xcode-wont-detect-an-iphone-5-device-with-ios-6-1-4) help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the iOS 6 SDK on XCode 5.

For that you need to have XCode 4 and XCode 5 on your Mac.

1. In terminal :

   ```
   cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
   ```
2. Create a symbolic link in this folder to the older SDK for example for me:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode4/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk ./iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
   ```

   [image]
3. Go to the Project settings and chose your SDK
4. Do only that for iPhoneOS. The support for the simulator need to be done from the XCode Preference menu

Answer (score 0):

Go with this step:

> Xcode >> preferences >> Download panel(9th one)(see it in screenshot-1) >> Components >> ios
>   6.0 simulator (see it in screenshot-2) >> click on download.

then you have to wait for download and then you have get different ios 6 and ios 7 .

**screenshot-1**:

[image]

**screenshot-2**:
[image]

Comment: Dhaval  sir i need your help

Comment: @ParvendraKumar invite me on any chat room

Comment: i try but i cant do this....I not find any option for chat on your profile